# Flutter: future not returned after closing alert dialog

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog, future, flutter-dependencies

I created a http method in Flutter like below:

```
  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) {
    const url = 'https://flutter-shop-3de16.firebaseio.com/products';
    return http
        .post(
      url,
      body: json.encode({
        'title': product.title,
        'description': product.description,
        'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
        'price': product.price,
        'isFavorite': product.isFavorite,
      }),
    )
        .then((response) {
      ...
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    });
  }
```

**I know that my `url` is wrong because i want to get error.**

In **.catchError** i throw an error and in the main page by provider i used `addProduct` like this:

```
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .addProduct(_editedProduct)
          .catchError((error) {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('An error occurred!'),
            content: Text('Something went wrong.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Okay'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).then((_) {
        print('after catch accoured');
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      });
    }
  }
```

I `catchError` i got error and i show an alert dialog.After tap on `Okay` button i want to execute `then` block so i returned `showDialog` because it return a future.

But i do not know why

```
.then((_) {
            print('after catch accoured');
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
            });
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          });
        }
```

No to run after alert dialog is closed?

Answer (score 3):

[image: notice]

- make sure using `return showDialog<Null>()` instead of `return showDialog()`
- also have a try-catch with `throw error` when using `json.decode()` inside products provider

Answer (score 0):

```
return showDialog(
         context: context,
         builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
           title: Text('An error occurred!'),
           content: Text('Something went wrong.'),
           actions: <Widget>[
             FlatButton(
               child: Text('Okay'),
               onPressed: () {
                 Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
               },
             )
           ],
         ),
       ).then((value) => null);
```

the above `then((value) => null );` will solve your problem, it would help you i think.

Answer (score -1):

The `then` block will run after the main Future; it won't run after `catchError`. If you want to run a piece of code after `catchError`, use a `whenComplete` block.

```
  Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .addProduct(_editedProduct)
          .catchError((error) {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('An error occurred!'),
            content: Text('Something went wrong.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Okay'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).whenComplete(() { // This will run after execution
        print('after catch accoured');
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: If i added whenComplete , Alert dialog is not appeared. @UmutSeven

Answer (score -1):

Below code should solve your issue. moving then statement after show dialog would make it work again.

```
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
        .addProduct(_editedProduct)
        .catchError((error) {
      return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) =>
            AlertDialog(
              title: Text('An error occurred!'),
              content: Text('Something went wrong.'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Okay'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
      ).then((_) {
        print('after catch accoured');
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      });;
    });
```